# navigation button(button next,button previous,button first and button last )

Tags: mysql, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to codes for navigation button, like I'm trying to code for button next ,button previous, button first and button last in my cotroller, but it seem that I'm having problem with my date where the index is all my date with  the index gives me red line. The rest don't give me any problems except the date in the index area, where I have the

```
public void next(int index)throws SQLExeception{
```

#### my  navigation controller

```
package hotel.management.system;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author PHILSERVER
 */
public class CustomersnavigationController implements Initializable {


    private ArrayList<String> fullname = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> nationality = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> countryofresidence = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList <String> dateofbirth = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> profession = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> passport = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> roomtype = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> roomnumber = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> dateofarrival = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> goingtowhere = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> numberofgroup = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> dateofdepature = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> periodstayed = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> numberofnight = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> roomrate = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> total = new ArrayList<>();
    private int index = 0;


     private LocalDate date;
     private String selectedDate;
      @FXML
    private TextField tfNumberofgroup;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfProfession;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfRoomnumber;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfRoomtype;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfTotal;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfPassport;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfFullname;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfNumberofnight;

    @FXML
    private Button Last;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfNationality;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfRoomrate;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker dpDate;

    @FXML
    private Button Next;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker dpDepaturedate;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfGoingtowhere;

    @FXML
    private Button Previous;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfSearch;

    @FXML
    private Button First;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker dpArrivaldate;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfCountryofresidence;

    @FXML
    private Connection con;

     @FXML
    private java.sql.Statement stmt;

     @FXML
    private ResultSet rs;

    @FXML
    void search(ActionEvent event) {
if (tfSearch.getText().equals("")){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Enter fullname please !!!");
    }else{
    if(checkName()){
   search();

}else{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"fullname does not exist");
}

   }
    }
     @FXML
    void first(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
index=0;
        move();
        next(index);
    } 
    @FXML
    void next(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
index=index+1;
      move();
     next(index);

    }
     @FXML
    void previous(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
if (index <0) {
            index = 0;
        } else {
            index=index-1;
            move();
            next(index);

    }
    }
    @FXML
    void last(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
 move();
      index=fullname.size()-1;
      next(index);
    }

     private void move() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to register class "+e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/level2","root","addison");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to connect to database "+e.getMessage());
        }


        try {
            String sql;
            sql = "select * from customerinformaton";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                fullname.add(rs.getString("fullname"));
                nationality.add(rs.getString("nationality"));
                countryofresidence.add(rs.getString("countryofresidence"));
                dateofbirth.add(rs.getString("dateofbirth"));
                profession.add(rs.getString("profession"));
                passport.add(rs.getString("passport"));
                roomtype.add(rs.getString("roomtype"));
                roomnumber.add(rs.getString("roomnumber"));
                dateofarrival.add(rs.getString("dateofarrival"));
                goingtowhere.add(rs.getString("goingtowhere"));
                numberofgroup.add(rs.getString("numberofgroup"));
                dateofdepature.add(rs.getString("dateofdepature"));
                numberofnight.add(rs.getString("numberofnight"));
                roomrate.add(rs.getString("roomrate"));
                total.add(rs.getString("total"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to retrieve record "+e.getMessage());
}


 }  

    private void next(int index) throws SQLException {
        tfFullname.setText(fullname.get(index));
        tfNationality.setText(nationality.get(index));
        tfCountryofresidence.setText(countryofresidence.get(index));
        java.sql.Date d7 = rs.getDate(index);
        dpDate.setValue(d7.toLocalDate());
        tfProfession.setText(profession.get(index));
        tfPassport.setText(passport.get(index));
        tfRoomtype.setText(roomtype.get(index));
        tfRoomnumber.setText(roomnumber.get(index));
        java.sql.Date d4 = rs.getDate(index);
        dpArrivaldate.setValue(d4.toLocalDate());
        tfGoingtowhere.setText(goingtowhere.get(index));
        tfNumberofgroup.setText(numberofgroup.get(index));
        java.sql.Date d6 = rs.getDate(index);
        dpDepaturedate.setValue(d6.toLocalDate());
        tfNumberofnight.setText(numberofnight.get(index));
        tfRoomrate.setText(roomrate.get(index));
        tfTotal.setText(total.get(index));
}

   private boolean checkName(){
    try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to register class "+e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/level2","root","addison");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to connect to database "+e.getMessage());
        }
         try{
             String sql;
             sql="select * from customerinformation where fullname='"+tfSearch.getText()+"'";
             rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
             if(rs.next()){
             return true;
             }
         }catch (SQLException e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"unable to retrieve record"+ e.getMessage());
         }
         return false;
         }

      private void search(){
       try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to register class "+e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/level2","root","addison");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to connect to database "+e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            String sql;
            sql = "select * from customerinformation where fullname='"+tfSearch.getText()+"'";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){

            tfFullname.setText(rs.getString("fullname"));
            tfNationality.setText(rs.getString("nationality"));
            tfCountryofresidence.setText(rs.getString("countryofresidence"));
            java.sql.Date dm = rs.getDate("Dateofbirth");
            dpDate.setValue(dm.toLocalDate());
            tfProfession.setText(rs.getString("profession"));
            tfPassport.setText(rs.getString("passport"));
            tfRoomtype.setText(rs.getString("roomtype"));
            tfRoomnumber.setText(rs.getString("roomnumber"));
            java.sql.Date da = rs.getDate("dateofarrival");
            dpArrivaldate.setValue(da.toLocalDate());
            tfGoingtowhere.setText(rs.getString("goingtowhere"));
            tfNumberofgroup.setText(rs.getString("numberofgroup"));
            java.sql.Date dd = rs.getDate("Dateofdepature");
            dpDepaturedate.setValue(dd.toLocalDate());
            tfNumberofnight.setText(rs.getString("numberofnight"));
            tfRoomrate.setText(rs.getString("roomrate"));
            tfTotal.setText(rs.getString("total"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to retrieve record "+e.getMessage());
        }   
    }
    public static final LocalDate LD (String date)
    { 
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        CharSequence dateString = null;
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
        return localDate; 
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to question: Since your application seems to be mainly JavaFX based you should be using a `javafx.scene.control.Dialog`, or more specifically in your case an [`Alert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html), rather than `JOptionPane`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a compile time error, which means you need to explaing what *"gives me red line"* means. If it means *"throws an exception"*  you should include the stacktrace in the question, if not, post the compile time error.(But if it compiles I know where the error comes from: you always call `move()` before using that method, but this leaves the cursor after the last element. `index` seems to denote the row, but you're trying to access that (1-based) column index from a non-existing row.)You should create a class containing all the data instead of using 15 different`List`s btw.